# Stream video from Raspberry Pi's USB port to server

Tags: video, usb, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I'm trying to grab a video stream being input into the Pi's USB port, process and encode it, and stream it out to a server. Is there a way to do this, or just to grab the stream and forward it to the server (over the internet)?

In other words, I want to grab a generic video feed from a USB port, do some custom video processing in real time, encode the output to `H.264`, and then stream the output to a server.  I don't mind using C++, Java, Python, etc. but I need to keep latency down.  I also don't mind using `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Hello, there are a lot of tutorials in internet how to stream video from pi and you can easily search them. Question is to generic and not comply with general questions guidelines.  There is more specific question here http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23182/how-to-stream-video-from-raspberry-pi-camera-and-watch-it-live. Here is some serach results from Google:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-remote-webcam/

http://gtrifonov.com/2015/07/02/streaming-live-video-from-raspberrypi-to-azure-media-services/

Answer (score -2):

there are a lot of tutorials in internet how to stream video from pi and you can easily search them. Question is to generic and not comply with general questions guidelines.  There is more specific question here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23182/how-to-stream-video-from-raspberry-pi-camera-and-watch-it-live. Here is some serach results from Google:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-remote-webcam/

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/stream-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-to-web-browsers-even-on-ios-and-android

http://gtrifonov.com/2015/07/02/streaming-live-video-from-raspberrypi-to-azure-media-services/
Based on what is your requirements you need select appropriate tutorial.